# How do I get javascript to print out a property that is in an object in another object

Tags: javascript, object

```
var customerData = {
  'Joe': {
    visits: 1
  },
  'Carol': {
    visits: 2
  },
  'Howard': {
    visits: 3,
  },
  'Carrie': {
    visits: 4
  }
};
```

I want to print out the number of visits for each person.
Thanks

Comment: Is this not a duplicate?

Comment: Have you not tried *anything* or done *any* research before asking?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for in` loop to iterate over the object to access the `visits` property.

```
for(let key in customerData) {
   console.log("Visits by " + key + ' - ' + customerData[key].visits);
}
```

For each iteration, `key` would be `Joe` and ...

`customerData[key]` will give you access to the nested object in case of

`Joe` --> `{ visits: 1 }`

**[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbwds2a7/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var key in customerData) {
    console.log(key + " visits = " + customerData[key].visits);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Chrome** and **Opera** all you need is:

```
console.debug(customerData);
```

You can introspect the object parts right there on the console, by clicking on the triangles:

[image]

---

In **Firefox** there's a little more work to it.  First click on the italics *Object* in the console.

[image]

Then inspect the parts under the Object pane.

[image]